# setw() does nothing when in a line with a variable (g++ in Windows terminal)

Tags: c++, g++, setw

In the line below, `setw(3)` is ignored when I compile:

```
cout << setw(3) << sym;
```

I found out that not using a variable works fine:

```
cout << setw(3) << "*";
```

Below are both versions of the full code (the only difference is in line 13) and an image of both of them being compiled and ran.

Not working as intended:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

char sym = '*';

int main(){

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++){
            cout << setw(3) << sym;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Working as intended:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

char sym = '*';

int main(){

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++){
            cout << setw(3) << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Image of each being compiled and run:

[image: image of each being compiled and run]

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/jnhTs631h)

Comment: @justANewbie: That's not a reproduction. OP mentions g++ in a windows terminal !

Comment: @engf-010 I'm sure it's the same, but to make it sure I test it in my command line and it still produces the expect result.

Comment: @justANewbie: Still ,I don't think OP is making this up. different compiler versions may be.

Comment: For further clarification my compiler was set up by following this: https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~alee/g++/g++.html

Comment: I just ran both versions of the code using g++ 9.3.0 and both work perfectly fine. It was just the older compiler that was messing up.